# Babun, tmux, cygwin bind command not found

Tags: cygwin, bind, key-bindings, tmux, babun

I have problems to .tmux.conf I have install babon and tmux over cygwin.

But I have problems with "bind" command, this not found.

```
{ ~ }  » bind                                                                               ~ 127
zsh: command not found: bind
```

I looked for with:

```
{ ~ }  » pact find bind                                                                         ~
Working directory is /setup
Mirror is http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/
setup.ini taken from the cache

Searching for installed packages matching bind:
bind
bind-utils
girepository-Keybinder3.0
libbind9_140
libbind9_160
libkeybinder0
libkeybinder3.0_0
python-keybinder

Searching for installable packages matching bind:
bind
bind-debuginfo
bind-doc
bind-utils
girepository-Keybinder0.0
girepository-Keybinder3.0
keybinder-debuginfo
keybinder3.0-debuginfo
libbind9-devel
libbind9_140
libbind9_160
libindicator-common
libindicator-debuginfo
libindicator-devel
libindicator-tools
libindicator3-devel
libindicator3-tools
libindicator3_7
libindicator7
libkeybinder-devel
libkeybinder-doc
libkeybinder0
libkeybinder3.0-devel
libkeybinder3.0-doc
libkeybinder3.0_0
lua5.1-keybinder
python-keybinder
rpcbind
rpcbind-debuginfo
ruby-binding_of_caller
ruby-binding_of_caller-doc
xapian-bindings
xapian-bindings-debuginfo
```

I don't know what ocurrs.

Thanks a lot,

Oliver Noguera

Answer (score 0):

The package `bind` has no program called `bind`

From the package contents at
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/bind/bind-9.11.2-2.P1
you can see that the executable is called `named` and it is
not locate on `/usr/bin/` but on `/usr/sbin/`

```
bind: DNS server

    2018-02-04 06:31           0 etc/
    2018-02-04 06:31        3923 etc/bind.keys
    2018-02-04 06:31        9747 usr/bin/arpaname.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       18451 usr/sbin/ddns-confgen.exe
    2018-02-04 06:31         708 usr/sbin/dnssec-checkds
    2018-02-04 06:31         710 usr/sbin/dnssec-coverage
    2018-02-04 06:32       49683 usr/sbin/dnssec-dsfromkey.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       48147 usr/sbin/dnssec-importkey.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       54803 usr/sbin/dnssec-keyfromlabel.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       61459 usr/sbin/dnssec-keygen.exe
    2018-02-04 06:31         701 usr/sbin/dnssec-keymgr
    2018-02-04 06:32       45075 usr/sbin/dnssec-revoke.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       52755 usr/sbin/dnssec-settime.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       99859 usr/sbin/dnssec-signzone.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       45075 usr/sbin/dnssec-verify.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       11283 usr/sbin/genrandom.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       12307 usr/sbin/isc-hmac-fixup.exe
    2018-02-04 06:31           0 usr/sbin/lwresd -> named.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       30227 usr/sbin/named-checkconf.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       28691 usr/sbin/named-checkzone.exe
    2018-02-04 06:31           0 usr/sbin/named-compilezone -> named-checkzone.exe
    2018-02-04 06:30        4156 usr/sbin/named-config
    2018-02-04 06:32       11283 usr/sbin/named-journalprint.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       11283 usr/sbin/named-nzd2nzf.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32      781843 usr/sbin/named.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       11283 usr/sbin/nsec3hash.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       17939 usr/sbin/rndc-confgen.exe
    2018-02-04 06:32       32275 usr/sbin/rndc.exe
    2018-02-04 06:31           0 usr/sbin/tsig-keygen -> ddns-confgen.exe
    2018-02-04 06:31         841 usr/share/man/man1/arpaname.1.gz
    ....
```

Comment: Not is this bind package, is binding keys for tmux.

Comment: bind for tmux is a command in `~/.tmux.conf`configuration file. Not for the command shell. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux